# how to enable event in ip camera (onvif)

Tags: node.js

I have a ip camera (onvif) its company is anxinshi, when camera detect face then i want this image in my software with nodejs language. ip camera support event but when  checked camera object, its not have any event so how can i enable event in ip camera.

```
const express = require('express');
const OnvifManager = require('onvif-nvt');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
OnvifManager.connect('192.168.1.100', 80, 'admin', '123456')
.then(results => {
        let camera = results
        if (camera.events) {
          camera.events.on('alarm', messages => {
            console.log('Messages Received:', messages)
          });
          camera.events.on('messages:error', error => {
            console.error('Messages Error:', error)
          });
        }
    });
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));`enter code here`
```

i want to get image when camera detect face.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I have a similar one with motion detection and events in my camera IP.